# Various offerings of SharePoint 2013 with respective to cost reduction?

Tags: 2013

SharePoint 2010 is used as a primary business collaboration/publishing/tooling platform and it is running on more than 40+ servers(6 different farms), we are paying huge amount as a license cost for various 3rd party software products like Newsgator, Axcelor, metalogix…Now we are looking for the cost saving and would like to know the various offerings of SharePoint 2013.

Please point me to the right direction.

Comment: any pointers to check the cost benefits of SharePoint 2013?

Comment: It would be helpful if you could be specific in what functionality you are using each of your third-party solutions to achieve.